# How to convert byte array recieved from SAP JCo to image in java...?

Tags: java, jco

In my Web service, I am receiving image array from SAP software via JCo. I am not able to convert that string to image.

Web Service Code :

```
       function String getImageWithStatus () {

            SapSystem system = new SapSystem();
            system.setClient("200");
            system.setHost("*************");
            system.setLanguage("en");
            system.setSystemNumber("02");
            system.setUser("*********");
            system.setPassword("***********");
            
            properties = new Properties();
            
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, system.getHost());
            
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, system.getSystemNumber());
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, system.getClient());
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, system.getUser());
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, system.getPassword());
            properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, system.getLanguage());
            System.out.println("******* Connection Parameter Set *******");

            JCoFunction function = repos.getFunction("ZCRM_STATUS_COMPLAINTS_MOB"); 
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("COMPLAINT_NUM", getcomplaintstatus);
            function.execute(dest);

            MyDestinationDataProvider myProvider = new MyDestinationDataProvider();

            dest = (JCoDestination) JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(SAP_SERVER);
            
            repos = dest.getRepository();

            byte[] byte_array = null;
            String status = "";
            String result = "";
            
            if (function.getExportParameterList().getString("FILE_CONTENT_BINARY") != null || !function.getExportParameterList().getString("FILE_CONTENT_BINARY").isEmpty()) {
                byte_array = function.getExportParameterList().getString("FILE_CONTENT_BINARY").getBytes();
                status = function.getExportParameterList().getString("STATUS");

                result = status + "$" + byte_array ;
            
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Image Found");
            }

             System.out.println("FILE_CONTENT_BINARY :" + byte_array);

      return result ;
  }
```

Comment: maybe there is a specific function to do that - some will answer soon - but you can use imageio if you are in java and that byte array is a legitimate image

Comment: Which function do you know. I can't use ImageIO as android does not supprot it...

Comment: You've got an array of bytes that might represent some kind of image in some kind of standardized format. Now what exactly is "an image in java" you're trying to create and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I know this is an old question, and hope you already have found the solution, but if this helps someone...
Have you tried to call `function.getExportParameterList().getByteArray("FILE_CONTENT_BINARY")` directly ?
By using `function.getExportParameterList().getString(String field)`, I believe you get the `String`representation of the value of a `JcoField`(which is the same as `jCoField.getString()`. Calling `getByteArray()` will bring the bytes of the String value.